# Right button in Listwidget

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

I have a method to delete the list of files on the `QListWidget`:

```
void MainWindow::ProvideContextMenu(const QPoint &pos) 
{
    QPoint item = ui->listWidget->mapToGlobal(pos);
    QMenu submenu;
    submenu.addAction("Delete");
    QAction* RightClick = submenu.exec(item);

    if(RightClick->text().contains("Delete"))
    {
        qDeleteAll(ui->listWidget->selectedItems());
    }
}
```

[image]

I have two problems:

1. After I right click and the delete button appears, if I click anywhere else other than delete, whole program closes. No idea why.
2. As you can see in the picture I have not selected the file, I just right click "on the file". Apparently this doesn't consider as selected. So every time I have to delete, first I have to select a file then right click. Is there any way around this?

Edit1: Still haven't found solution to 2nd problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [`QMenu::exec`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#exec) returns `nullptr` if no action was selected. You're dereferencing the null pointer afterwards - `RightClick->text()` and your program crashes. You have to avoid that.
2. [`QListWidget::selectedItems`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#selectedItems) returns a temporary `QList` (a copy), you won't change the state of the widget by manipulating that. Use `QListWidget`'s member function to remove its items.

The final code is:

```
if(RightClick && RightClick->text() == "Delete")
{
    for(auto item : ui->listWidget->selectedItems())
        delete ui->listWidget->takeItem(ui->listWidget->row(item));
}
```

**Edit:** Actually, what I answered in the second paragraph is not needed and what you had was right. At this point, I don't know why the list item doesn't get selected.

Comment: Thanks! you totally solved the program stopping problem, but i stil can't fix the clicking problem

Comment: How did you connect `ProvideContextMenu`?

Comment: connect(ui->listWidgetOutput,SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)), this, SLOT(ProvideContextMenu(const QPoint &)));

Comment: I have no idea... I'm on Windows 7 with Qt 5.4 and it simply works. (You did `setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::ContextMenuPolicy::CustomContextMenu);`, right?)

Comment: Nope, where exactly should i do it?

Comment: That's strange. `ProvideContextMenu` should not be called if you don't write that. It's `ui->listWidget->set...`, do that in the constructor of `MainWindow`.

Comment: i have this in constructor:  " ui->listWidgetOutput->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);"

Comment: @user5603723 And the answers you got on your other question seem to solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah the 2nd problem isn't that significant, but the 1st problem was a dealbreaker.